# The transformation matrix of an dimetric projection onto the plane Z=0

Tags: matrices, geometry, projection, projection-matrices

I need to make a dimetric projection of the point onto the Z=0 plane. I found the transformation matrix of an ***isometric*** projection onto the Z=0 plane and it looks like this:

\begin{align*}
M &= \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
  cos (b) & 0 & -sin(b) & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  sin(b) & 0 & cos(b) & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & cos(a) & sin(a) & 0 \\
  0 & -sin(a) & cos(b) & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}\right]
* Morth(Z=0)
\end{align*}

As a result, I`ve got:
\begin{align*}
M &= \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
  cos (b) & sin(b)*sin(a) & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & cos(a) & 0 & 0 \\
  sin(b) & -sin(a)*cos(b) & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
But I cannot find such similar information about dimetric projection. How should the matrix look like in my case?

Comment: I have never seen the word, "dimetric". What does it mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson it is a type of axonometric projection ( https://www.qpractice.com/ncidq-glossary/axonometric-drawings/)